# Ways to convert special-purpoes-strings to Integers

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, hash

I need to have a in-memory data-structure of Key-Value pair (400 MB worth of data). I have following constraints on keys:

1. Both key and values are text strings of length 256 and 1024
   respectively.
2. Any key generally looks like k1k2k3k4k5, each k(i) being 4-8 byte string in itself. Some k(i) may or may not be there in the keys.
3. Every k(i) has 6-8 possibilities. However k3 and k4 have 256000 possibilities.
4. One might iterate the DS with prefix_key. DS should be optimized for this operation. This operation allocates an iterator i.e it iterates the whole DS and returns list of key-values that match prefix_key (e.g. "k1k2k3.*", k(i) defined as above). Every iteration iterates on this iterator(list). Freeing the iterator frees the list.

Coming up with DS for string keys makes key comparisons too expensive. And thus certain option for the DS (Hash, B+Tree) get ruled out.

My question is how creatively can we convert String keys to integer keys?The solution needs to have following property:

For a key pattern "k1k2k3.*" it should genarate upper and lower bound on integers so that based on these bounds only handful number of entries are looked up in the DS.

I am asking this question in context of [solution towards this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671680/best-suited-data-structure-for-prefix-based-searches)

Comment: B+tree gets ruled out as operations like add/delete/update/lookup/iterate involves key comparisons which in this case would be string comparisons. String comparisons are very expensive compared to integer comparisons. Hash gets ruled out as its un-ordered data set and not suitable for prefix based searching or regular expression based searching unless you can boil things down to handful number of keys that needs to be looked up. In both these cases converting the string key to integer key will help. It opens up new possibilities.

Comment: You can try a [Radix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree)

Comment: 1) can you enumerate the {k1,k2,k5} and the {k3,k4} ? 2) given a key, is it always possible to extract the k1..k5 components?

Comment: @joop: I didn't get your first question. For second, yes it is always possible to extract the components. E.g. Consider key value pairs like following:
(product.module.prod_version, 5.0)
(product.module.mod_version, 7.2)
(product.module.license, "LICENSE")
(product.anotherModule.mod_version, 3.4)
(product.anotherModule.license, "LIC2")
(product.module.feature1, Enabled) etc...
So all keys are dot delimited. you can see k1= product has only 1 possibility. k2 has 2 possibilities module and anothermodule. These key value pairs are only indicative to illustrate the point.

Comment: *enumerate* := assign a number to every value that can occur in the domain, so you can it refer to it by a number. (Just like the @MrSmith42 answer did, encoding it in 3+3+18+18+3 bits)

Comment: You need to edit your question and explain how you're searching these keys. You're apparently not looking for a simple hash table lookup. Rather, it appears you're looking for something that will allow you to search by the value of individual key segments. Are the key strings limited to a particular alphabet, or can they be any Unicode character? Should it be possible to search by any key segment, or just specific ones? How much memory are you willing to consume for the lookup table?

Answer (score 3):

Every k(i) has 6-8 possibilities. However k3 and k4 have 256000 possibilities.

If you can split key in k1 k2 k3 k4 k5, you could encode it like this:

```
 3 bits for k1  
 3 bits for k2  
18 bits for k3  
18 bits for k4  
 3 bits for k5
```

this makes 45bits.
So you can boil down your key to an integer between 0 and  2^45-1.
This seams to be a lot especially if you only use a few of the possible values for k3 and k4.

So I would take the 6 bits of k1 k2 for a exact mapping to an index and than depending how dense the k3 k4 is, some kind of tree structue for k3 and k4 and than an exact mapping to an index for k5 again.

Comment: How to look for all keys of the pattern "k1k2.*" with this calculation?